# Clustered standard errors are completely different in R than in STATA

Tags: r, stata, fixed-effects-model, clustered-standard-errors, plm

I'm trying to reproduce a study in R. Here are its core elements:

- study wants to measure the effect of a transit strike on highway
  delay
- independent variables:

  strike: binary

  dateresidual: difference from the start of strike (negative for pre-strike, positive for during strike)

  dateresidual*strike

  4 binary variables for 4/5 weekdays
- each observation is measured by one of the thousands of road sensors (sensorid) for a particular hour of the day. So each vds would have multiple observations per day.
- The STATA code ran this with cluster(sensorid) and absorb(sensorid), meaning the standard errors are clustered at the sensor level and sensor id is the fixed effect.
- The regression has a weight for highway length/total flow

  > areg delay strike dateresidual datestrike mon tue wed thu [aw=weight], cluster(sensorid) absorb(sensorid)
- I have tried to run this in r using plm. I was able to get the exact same estimates:

> plm1<-plm(delay~strike+dateresidual+datestrike+mon+tue+wed+thu,mydata,model="within",index=c("sensorid"))

However, when I tried to run the clustered standard errors at sensor id, the standard errors are way off from the stata results and the effects are no longer significant.

> coeftest(plm1,vcovHC)

Could you tell me what I should tweak in coeftest to represent what the code in STATA does? Or should I use a different package?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155638/clustered-standard-errors-in-r-using-plm-with-fixed-effects/33160294#33160294) for one potential difference. Also, note that the spelling is Stata since it is not an acronym.

Answer (score 1):

First, Stata uses [a finite sample correction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33160294/1187671) that R does not use when clustering. Second, `areg` is designed for datasets with many groups, but not a number that grows with the sample size. One example is states in the US. Your `plm` is much more like `xtreg, fe`. Although the point estimates produced by `areg` and `xtreg, fe` are the same, the estimated VCEs differ with clustering because the commands make different assumptions about whether the number of groups/sensors increases with the sample size. When you cluster with `xtreg, fe`, the asymptotics relies on the number of groups going to infinity. So this is not an apples to apples comparison.

In your setting, `xtreg, fe` seems more suitable since many sensors could be added. If you have to replicate `areg`'s output, you can use `felm`.

Here is an econometrically stupid example demonstrating these claims. Here I am using Roger Newson's `rsource` to run R from within Stata, but it is not strictly necessary:

```
. rsource, terminator(END_OF_R)
Assumed R program path: "/usr/local/bin/R"

Beginning of R output
> suppressPackageStartupMessages({
+         require(plm)
+         require(lmtest)
+         library(foreign)
+         library(lfe)
+         data(Cigar)
+ })
> xtregfe <- plm(sales ~ price, model = 'within', data = Cigar)
> G <- length(unique(Cigar$state))
> c <- G/(G - 1)
> coeftest(xtregfe,c * vcovHC(xtregfe, type = "HC1", cluster = "group"))

t test of coefficients:

      Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
price -0.20984    0.03575 -5.8697 5.503e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

> areg<-felm(sales ~ price | state | 0 | state, Cigar)
> coeftest(areg)

t test of coefficients:

       Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
price -0.209840   0.036348 -5.7731 9.672e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

> write.dta(Cigar,"~/Desktop/Cigar.dta")
> 
End of R output

. 
. use "~/Desktop/Cigar.dta", clear
(Written by R.              )

. xtset state year
       panel variable:  state (strongly balanced)
        time variable:  year, 63 to 92
                delta:  1 unit

. xtreg sales price, fe cluster(state)

Fixed-effects (within) regression               Number of obs     =      1,380
Group variable: state                           Number of groups  =         46

R-sq:                                           Obs per group:
     within  = 0.2559                                         min =         30
     between = 0.1007                                         avg =       30.0
     overall = 0.0969                                         max =         30

                                                F(1,45)           =      34.45
corr(u_i, Xb)  = 0.0329                         Prob > F          =     0.0000

                                 (Std. Err. adjusted for 46 clusters in state)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
       sales |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       price |  -.2098402   .0357498    -5.87   0.000     -.281844   -.1378364
       _cons |   138.3669   2.456008    56.34   0.000     133.4202    143.3135
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     sigma_u |  25.678164
     sigma_e |  15.174773
         rho |  .74116131   (fraction of variance due to u_i)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. areg sales price, absorb(state) cluster(state)

Linear regression, absorbing indicators         Number of obs     =      1,380
Absorbed variable: state                        No. of categories =         46
                                                F(   1,     45)   =      33.33
                                                Prob > F          =     0.0000
                                                R-squared         =     0.7682
                                                Adj R-squared     =     0.7602
                                                Root MSE          =    15.1748

                                 (Std. Err. adjusted for 46 clusters in state)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
       sales |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       price |  -.2098402   .0363482    -5.77   0.000    -.2830493   -.1366312
       _cons |   138.3669   2.497119    55.41   0.000     133.3374    143.3963
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, `areg`/`felm` give you a price coefficient of -0.20984 with a clustered standard error of 0.03635. The panel fixed effect approaches both give you -0.20984, but with a smaller CSE of 0.03575.

Comment: the areg code is from the original study, only the R code is mine tho. I don't know the exact reason why they chose areg. Actually the SE is still very off in R. For example in STATA, the st.error for strike is 0.038 but in R its 0.778. Would the difference in areg and xtreg create such a big difference?

Comment: I don't have your data or even complete code, so I cannot really help. The code above manages to replicate output to five digits.

Comment: Here's the original study with the data and the code. The areg is on line 294 https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.104.9.2763
Thank you so much for helping me!!

Comment: I think there must be something wrong with how I applied it in coeftest, because the SE is so much bigger...

Comment: I don't have access to that journal, but maybe you can add the code they use and what your complete R code to the original post.

Comment: I also don't see the weighting in your R code, but if that was the issue the point estimate would also change.

Comment: Actually I'm able to replicate the results using lm_robust from the estimatr package https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27257142/robust-clustered-standard-errors-and-regression-weights-in-r
Thank you very much for your help though!

Comment: Staa's small sample adjustment is actually implemented in the `vcovHC` function of package `plm`: use `type="sss"`. For fixed effects models, you won't replicate Stata's results exactly as Stata leaves in a constant in it's fixed effect models. plm uses "amount of coefficients - 1" relative to Stata in the adjustment. For small samples, this gives slightly different results but will go unnoticed in large samples. See also these answers:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155638/clustered-standard-errors-in-r-using-plm-with-fixed-effects?rq=1