# Different standard errors in Stata and R for instrumental variables (ivreg)

Tags: r, stata, standard-error, instrumental-variables, clustered-standard-errors

Working with instrumental variables (IV), I noticed differences between reported standard errors in Stata (e.g., using ivreg2) and R (e.g., using AER:ivreg2). In R I found ways to replicate Stata's results for `ivreg2 ..., robust` but not for `ivreg ..., cluster(...)` and for the plain homoscedastic case:

- Stata: `ivreg2 y (x=z), cluster(cluster_id)` is not equivalent to
- R `coeftest(AER::ivreg(y ~ x | z , data=dat),type="HC2",vcov. = sandwich::vcovCL,cluster=dat$cluster_id)`

and

- Stata:  `ivreg2 y (x=z)` is not equivalent to
- R `coeftest(AER::ivreg(y ~ x | z , data=dat))`

**Question**:
How can I compute Stata-equivalent standard errors in R?

---

**For completeness:**
In simpler models there's usually a small difference between R and Stata that can be solved by telling R to compute standard errors in a certain way.

*OLS*

- Stata: `reg y x, robust` is equivalent to
- R: `lmtest::coeftest(lm(y ~ x , data=dat),vcov. = sandwich::vcovHC, type="HC1")`

and

- Stata: `reg y x, cluster(cluster_id)` is equivalent to
- R: `lmtest::coeftest(lm(y ~ x , data=dat),vcov. = sandwich::vcovCL, cluster=dat$cluster_id,type="HC1")`

Also for IV there are some equivalencies:

- Stata: `ivreg2 y (x=z), robust` is equivalent to
- R: `lmtest::coeftest(AER::ivreg(y ~ x | z , data=dat),type="HC0",vcov. = sandwich::vcovHC)`

**Data**: I'm attaching some simulated data to test/replicate the above statements: [link](https://hesss.org/old/test2.dta)

Comment: Small sample correction in Stata?

Comment: Not sure, the test data has N=25k and 500 clusters. But the differences in SEs are also relatively small. Any ideas how I switch this off in Stata or on in R?

Comment: Seems you are right. When I run `ivreg2 y (x=z), small` in Stata the results seem alike. So it seems the be driven by R always using small sample corrections while Stata only using those when explicitly asked for. Any ideas how I switch this off in R? My understanding would have been that "HC0" does that, but it seems that's not the case.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/359047/7071 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/33155638/1187671

Comment: Native Stata commands, like ivregress, tend to use the correction. ivreg2 is a community-contributed command, so it strays from that convention.

Comment: Thanks your linked help me solve my problem. It seems - in this particular case -  to be the other way around: Stata does not use the small sample corrections, but R does. Doing the opposite of what the link  suggested (dividing by G/(G-1)) instead of multiplying by it yields exactly equivalent results. If you write a short answer to this Question I will mark it as solved and also edit-in the respective lines of code for future reference.

Comment: it seems that ivregress and ivreg2 behave in the same way in this regard: They don't use the small sample correction by default.

Comment: You are right, I had that wrong. It looks like it’s not settled if the correction makes sense for IV.

Comment: What do you mean with "it's not settled". My question was only about how to obtain the same values in R than in Stata/where the difference comes from. This is sufficiently answered thanks to your help, by "undoing" the small sample correction in R

Comment: I mean that it's not clear in the literature if the small sample correction for IV always has better finite properties than the normal way. BTW, you can answer your own question here.